# Encoding issue in python 2.7.5 on red hat linux server 4.18

Tags: python, linux, pandas, python-2.7

we are migrating a python script from one server to another almost same configuration, only little difference in red hat linux  version

I am trying to concatenate  first 84 column and use MD5 to get the unique id for that particular row but same code run in two different server  linux both , i am getting two different md5 because .join is not giving the same result in both server, Also to note that this issue is not for all records some matches some not

code

```
{df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", encoding="utf-8", names=filedef_sourcefiles.ColumnNames.values.tolist(),
                          nrows=200, index_col=False, dtype=typeDict, keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
df["concat"] = ["".join(str(row)) for row in df[df.columns[:43]].values]
df["md5"] = [hashlib.md5(val.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest() for val in df["concat"]]
#df = df.drop("concat", 1)
df.head()}
```

the value of df["concat"] is not same for all

THE MD5 is same till 42 column but changes at 43 , reason one extra \n i see in the concat from one server  but not on another server

ex - u'NOr REIMBUuRtSrrwtBLE' u'ETHICAL MAfjfhfRKET' u'ATRyuIX']  frome server -1
u'NOr REIMBUuRtSrrwtBLE' u'ETHICAL MAfjfhfRKET'**\n** u'ATRyuIX']  from server 2

I observed one more thing when i print the result of

```
for row in df[df.columns[:43]].values:
     print(row)
```

both server have different place where the line breaks
let say **server1**
u'abcd' u'efgh' u'eyweyeyeyey' u'abcd' *\n*
u'kgf'
**server2**
u'abcd' u'efgh' u'eyweyeyeyey' *\n*
u'abcd'u'kgf'

Comment: How does the data get to each server?

Comment: I place the same file manually in both server, for testing but in processs it takes file from s3, download to its own location in server then it starts processing

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, review the tags (check the descriptions!) that you applied.